# find first non-null & non-empty string value

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, try-catch

I was using this to find the first non null value of a string:

```
def get_first_non_null_values(df):
    first_non_null_values = []
    try:
        kst = df['kst'].loc[df['kst'].first_valid_index()]
        first_non_null_values.append(kst)
    except:
        kst = df['kst22'].loc[df['kst22'].first_valid_index()]
        first_non_null_values.append(kst)
    return first_non_null_values


first_non_null_values = get_first_non_null_values(df_merged)
```

This worked but now in my new dataset, I have some null values and some `""` empty strings. How can I modify this such that I can extract the first value which is neither null not an empty string

Comment: Why don't you try to convert empty strings to np.nan firstly ?

Comment: Please provide an example of how you would use this function. Btw, the code in the expect block does nothing useful as you don't use/return the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['', np.nan, '', 1, 2, 3]})
print(df['col'].loc[df['col'].replace('', np.nan).first_valid_index()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `notnull`/`astype(bool)` and `idxmax`:

```
(df['col'].notnull()&df['col'].astype(bool)).idxmax()
```

Example input:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['', float('nan'), False, None, 0, 'A', 3]})
>>> df
     col
0       
1    NaN
2  False
3   None
4      0
5      A
6      3
```

output: `5`

null and truthy states:

```
     col  notnull  astype(bool)   both
0            True         False  False
1    NaN    False          True  False
2  False     True         False  False
3   None    False         False  False
4      0     True         False  False
5      A     True          True   True
6      3     True          True   True
```

##### first non empty string value:

If you're only interesting in strings that are not empty:

```
df['col'].str.len().gt(0).idxmax()
```

Comment: can you see the updated qs? I need to return the values from a function. Isn't your sol returning the ID?

Comment: can you give an example input dataframe and the expected output?